# Renaming an inner element cant be done as like renaming root element, while converting an xml to json using java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following code with me:

```java
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Xml2Json {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        
        jsonObject.put("employees", jsonObject.remove("users"));
        System.out.println(jsonObject); }}
```

It produces the output like below:

```
{"employees":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}.
```

But when i tried to rename 'report' to 'manual' in the same way,

```
jsonObject.put("Manual", jsonObject.remove("report"));
```

It didnt produced any chane in the ouput.

the output i needed is:

```
{"employees":{"Manual":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}
```

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.rename(map, oldKey, newKey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jsonObject.put("Manual", jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").remove("report"));
```

`report` is nested in `users` or `employees`. So first you have to get its root object.

#### Update

If you want to have a json as below

```
{"employees":{"Manual":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}
```

then your code should be like this:

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("users")
        .put("Manual", jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").remove("report"));
jsonObject.put("employees", jsonObject.remove("users"));
```

Comment: i have tried this before. Unfortunately, it will not provide the desired solution.                             {"Manual":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"users":{"type":{"direct":{"num":3}},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}
 it completely removes the root element.

Comment: @Iczapski   i have edited my code with my desired ouput. Please do check it.